# Gmail messes up my email fonts

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I am sending an email via php/html to a gmail address. The email displays fine in outlook & other clients but when I use the web interface of gmail, the fonts don't display correctly. For instance, I have this:

```
<html><body link="#00CCFF" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000">
<table width="100%">
<tr align="left" style="color:#000000"; height="25px"><td>Col0</td><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td><td>Col4</td></tr>
<tr align="left" style="color:#00CCFF; font-size:9px;"><td><a href="http://www.example.com">click</a></td><td colspan="4">row1</td></tr>
<tr align="left" style="color:#00CCFF; font-size:9px;"><td><a href="http://www.example.com">click</a></td><td colspan="4">row2</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Gmail changes the color of my hyperlinks to their default blue.
In my table row, the color displays correctly but the font size is bigger (looks like gmail changed it to a standard size)

thx!

Comment: No idea but I've balanced it up again.

Comment: To everyone voting to move this to superuser: This is an HTML/CSS-in-email question, which is StackOverflow territory.

Comment: how do we get it back to stackoverflow? very annoying!

Comment: Could you put your actual code in the question? Other HTML mails display fine, so somethings probably wrong in your HTML. (It might well be that GMail is more strict than other clients)

Comment: I've flagged both questions for moderator attention so things should move. However, if you don't include your code then it's an easy mistake for people to make.

Comment: As I remember, gmail has built-in HTML filter. That was done to protect their document layout (not to disrupt the page layout).

Comment: Please see this question for a good answer and solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502111/outlook-2010-not-respecting-css-even-font-tags-for-every-text/20461888#20461888

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)'s an interesting and updated list of CSS capabilities of the most popular web/desk based email readers. Check it out first, it's a good start.

On the other hand, consider that GMail is actually a web page, so it's obvious and expected that body attrs will not be used. Consider looking for a CSS based solution.

If you want to make sure that the attr is into the final source, use FireBug to see the final HTML used in the web client. There's not any better strategy, because you're watching exactly what the HTML filter gives to the browser.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You've put your CSS for the links in the body tag, which Gmail will strip because the body tag is already created by the Gmail interface around your email. Your only solution is to use inline CSS in the `<a>` tag, like this:

```
<a href="#" style="color: #123456;">text</a>
```

Unfortunately, you cannot style active and visited links via inline CSS.

Answer (score 1):

At present, it seems that Gmail doesn't support `<style>` tags or `link/visited/active/hover` CSS link-state selectors.

However, you can try to simulate this behavior with JavaScript:

- simulate *a:link* with the `onMouseOut` event in combination with `style="color:#XXX;"`.
- simulate *a:hover* with the `onMouseOver`
  event.
- simulate *a:active* with the `onMouseDown` event.

e.g.:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"
   style="color:#00CCFF;" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#00CCFF'"
   onMouseOver="this.style.color='#FFFF00'"
   onMouseDown="this.style.color='#FF0000'">click</a>
```

You can probably use the `click` event to set a "visited" style, but it'll reset when the page reloads, and you'll need to persist it (temporarily) - possibly by replacing the `onMouseOut` event handler's `style.color` value.

I haven't tried this code in Gmail, I'll leave that to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem. Instead of **px** use the font-size in **pt**, it worked for me.

Comment: Probably better using `em` instead of `pt` to allow the text to scale on tablets and phones.